Is "people from A to B years old" considered bad writing? Grammarly suggested "people aged A to B years

Looking at the information in more detail, we can see that people between the ages of 55 and 64 consumed the most fruit and vegetables per day, with 33% of males and 35% of females eating five or more portions. The figures for those from 65 to 74 years old were slightly lower, at 28% of males and 30% of females.

Grammarly suggested that I change the bolded part to those aged 65 to 74 years. Why?
Firstly, I think my version is fine.
Secondly, I find those aged 65 to 74 years a bit strange without old and from, I would write those aged from 65 to 74 or those aged from 65 to 74 years old.
So, which versions are correct?

The OP's version is acceptable, but I would place a hyphen between the figures omitting "from…to" i.e. aged 65-74.

The figures for people aged 65-74 were slightly lower, at 28% of males and 30% of females.

The previous phrase "between the ages of 55 and 64 consumed…" is acceptable without tagging ‘years old’, likewise “The figures for those aged 65 to 74 were slightly lower” is grammatical and idiomatic.
I'd omit years, we never say someone's age is 65 years, it's either "She's 65 years old" or "She's 65".

There seems a lot of style guide variation e.g. UK government wants "aged 4 to 16 years", but U of Nottingham wants an en dash, and some seem to suggest rephrasing.

@StuartF the OP's text is formal but not literature reserved  for government departments or aimed at  the general public, though I was surprised to see: Use ‘aged 4 to 16 years’, not ‘4-16 years’  I don't think an en-dash is absolutely necessary: 65-74 vs 65–74, I prefer the hyphen myself.  I think I already mentioned that "65 years old" and "65" were both acceptable and idiomatic. The main point to take away is that Grammarly was wrong to suggest the OP had to omit "old"

In the US, "aged 65 to 74 years" would be an outlier.  We do not say "years" there.  You might find it in a government document somewhere, but it's not what people say.  But it wouldn't hurt to say "adults aged 65-74".

Note that, as @StuartF mentioned, what you should not do is use a hyphen: -. The correct punctuation to indicate a numeric range is the en dash; –.

@PaulTanenbaum that's a matter of opinion, I see ages separated by a hyphen as well as with an en dash on the Internet. You can't say  the hyphen usage is incorrect, because style is subjective not objective but I will concede that "years" with ages such as 13 to 18 Years and 13-18 years, definitely a hyphen there,  are used. I guess I mustn't have been paying attention.

Google hits for "13 to 18 years“

@Mari-LouA, no more a matter of opinion than any other use of punctuation.
